# seaborn error 'Input data must be a pandas object to reorder'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

ValueError: Input data must be a pandas object to reorder.
detail ;
python 3.1, lib seaborn 0.12.

> ValueError: Input data must be a pandas object to reorder

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='white')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/dqlab-dataset/customer_segments.txt", 
                   sep="\t")
plt.clf()
  
# Menyiapkan kolom kategorikal  
kolom_kategorikal = ['Jenis Kelamin','Profesi','Tipe Residen']  

# Membuat canvas
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(7,10))
```

---

```
# Membuat plot untuk setiap kolom kategorikal  
for i, kol in enumerate(kolom_kategorikal):  
    # Membuat Plot
    sns.countplot(df[kol], order = df[kol].value_counts().index, ax = axs[i])  
    axs[i].set_title('\nCount Plot %s\n'%(kol), fontsize=15)
      
    # Memberikan anotasi  
    for p in axs[i].patches:  
        axs[i].annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.0f'),  
                        (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),  
                        ha = 'center',  
                        va = 'center',  
                        xytext = (0, 10),  
                        textcoords = 'offset points') 
          
    # Setting Plot  
    sns.despine(right=True,top = True, left = True)  
    axs[i].axes.yaxis.set_visible(False) 
    plt.setp(axs[i])
    plt.tight_layout()

# Tampilkan plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need specify parameter `x`, so change:

```
sns.countplot(df[kol], order = df[kol].value_counts().index, ax = axs[i])
```

to:

```
sns.countplot(x = df[kol], order = df[kol].value_counts().index, ax = axs[i])
```

Or:

```
sns.countplot(x = kol, order = df[kol].value_counts().index, ax = axs[i], data=df)
```

Comment: @Margubillah If your problem is solved, please adopt the answer for other people.